# JAX-RS Exception Mapper not working in Grizzly container

Tags: exception, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, grizzly, exceptionmapper

Working on a Jersey web application with a team, as the project got bigger and bigger, we decided to switch from Tomcat to Grizzly to allow deploying parts of the project on different port numbers. What I've found out now, that the custom exception handling we have fails to work now, instead I always get the grizzly html page.

Example exception:

```
public class DataNotFoundException extends RuntimeException{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1622261264080480479L;

public DataNotFoundException(String message) {
    super(message);
    System.out.println("exception constructor called"); //this prints
 }
}
```

Mapper:

```
@Provider
public class DataNotFoundExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<DataNotFoundException>{

public DataNotFoundExceptionMapper() {
    System.out.println("mapper constructor called"); //doesnt print
}

@Override
public Response toResponse(DataNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("toResponse called"); //doesnt print
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage(), 404, "No documentation yet."); 
    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
            .entity(errorMessage)
            .build();
      //ErrorMessage is a simple POJO with 2 string and 1 int field
 }

}
```

I'm not sure where is the problem source, if needed I can provide more information/code. What's the problem, what can I try?

**EDIT**:

Main.class:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * Main method.
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

...

    List<ServerInfo> serverList = new ArrayList<ServerInfo>();

    serverList.add(new ServerInfo(
            "api",8450,
            new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(
                    the.package.was.here.ApiResource.class)
            ));             

    for(ServerInfo server : serverList) {
        server.start();
    }

    System.out.println("Press enter to exit...");
    System.in.read();

    for(ServerInfo server : serverList) {
        server.stop();
    }

}
}
```

**EDIT2:**
based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803204/exceptionmapper-not-work-in-grizzly) question I've tried using this `ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, "true"`property, which only helped a little. I still get the html grizzly page when the exception happens, but now I see my exception (+stack trace) in the body of the page.

Comment: The mapper probably isn't being registered. Can you show your app setup/configuration.

Comment: do you mean the code which starts the servers? dependencies?

Comment: Just server code, at least showing the ResourceConfig

Comment: I was not part of the migration, so I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, I'll edit the question the class that imports org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

Comment: You're not showing using this class. The important information is in the creation of the ResourceConfig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only registering one resource class for the entire application

```
new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(
        eu.arrowhead.core.api.ApiResource.class
)
```

The mapper needs to be registered also

```
new ResourceConfig().registerClasses(
        eu.arrowhead.core.api.ApiResource.class,
        YourMapper.class)
)
```

You can also use package scanning, which will pick up all classes and automatically register them, if they are annotated with `@Path` or `@Provider`

```
new ResourceConfig().packages("the.packages.to.scan")
```

Comment: thanks, i'll try it out :) i'll accept your answer when I got it working

Comment: this is working for me, same issue were encountered and after register the mappers , i able to get the mapped exception. thanks for the answer